# How do I avoid the leaning toothpick syndrome in awk?

Tags: awk, regular-expression

When matching patterns with `/` in them, having to escape the `/` quickly becomes unwieldy, ugly:

```
/\/usr\/share\/man\//
```

With sed, perl or Vim, I would use a different delimiter for the regex, say `:`:

```
sed '\:/usr/share/man/: do something'
perl -ne 'print if m:/usr/share/man/:'
:g:/usr/share/man/: do something " Vim
```

How can I avoid this awk? Something like:

```
awk ':/usr/share/man/: {do something}'
```

The best I can think of is to use a variable:

```
awk -v pat='/usr/share/man/' '$0 ~ pat {do something}'
```

But that is very verbose compared to the sed/perl/vim method.

---

Of course, there might be other ways to match paths like `/usr/share/man/`, but that's not the only place where `/` could appear in a pattern.

Comment: you could do `'$0 ~ "/usr/share/man/" {do something}'` instead of using variable...

Comment: @Sundeep I could, but the reason I brought it out is that this way I get to retain a layer of quoting (compare `-v pat='"/'` vs `'$0 ~ "\"/"'`).

Comment: yup, that is true... and there is whole lot of escaping trouble while assigning something to awk variable which includes bash variables.. for ex: `-v regex="^\\\s*$1\\\>"` ... I don't think there is a way to use different regex delimiter than `/regex/` so will have to use whatever fits case by case basis

Answer (score 1):

Just change `/testregexp/` with `$0 ~ "testregexp"`

Simple exemple:

```
$ echo "a/b/c" | awk ' ( $0 ~ "a/b/c" ) { print "we have a winner" ; }'
we have a winner
```

another exemple

```
regexp='some regexp "with /lots/ of double quotes" "everywhere"'
awk -v reg="${regexp}" ' ( $0 ~ reg ) { action here... }'
```

Comment: See comments on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Awk by itself doesn't have any easy, straightforward antidote for this.  In the general case, switching to Perl (or down to `sed` for simple tasks) is the common workaround.